# Unit Testing and in C with Jenkins CI automated builds

Tags: c, unit-testing, jenkins-plugins, xunit, build-server

As many others, I am new to Jenkins CI. But I am improving!

So... I have setup a build server at work, with Windows Server 2012 r2.
I am trying to setup a unit test in Jenkins for my simple C code in Notepad++.

I have written my own helloworldTest.c with simpleCtest as unit test framework (see below).

Q1: Am I supposed to use this test, executing the binary file?

Q2: If so..
How do I "publish my test result"? Is this where I need to use a plugin from Jenkins, such as [xUnit](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin)? How? (I am seeing something about a xml-file...)
If not.. I would like to get some ideas, please.

Q3: I have stumbled upon **gcovr.com** in my searches about unit tests. Is this just another way? Why/How?

I will later on continue with setup code coverage. But I do not know if that will be effected by the choices above.

---

*What I have at the moment*

I have installed Jenkins at my localhost:8081.
I have installed scm-manager for my repositories at my localhost:8082.
I have setup configuration/connection between my Jenkins project and my repository. The builds are triggered when pushed to master. This works fine.

My Hello World project includes:

- helloworld.h
- helloworldTest.c
- A directory with the local unit test: simpleCtest (including the testfile tests.h)

These will show in my Jenkins Project workspace as well.

I've downloaded that simpleCtest unit test framework from **simplectest.sourceforge.net**

**helloworld.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Declaration
const char * HelloWorld();

//Definitions
const char * HelloWorld(){
     return "Hello World!";
}
```

**helloworldTest.c**

```
// include test definitions
#include "simplectest/tests.h"
#include "helloworld.h"

// Start the overall test suite
START_TESTS()

    START_TEST("Hello World Test")
       ASSERT_EQUALS("Hello World!", HelloWorld())
    END_TEST()

    START_TEST("Count World")
        ASSERT_EQUALS(12, strlen(HelloWorld()))
    END_TEST()

// End the overall test suite
END_TESTS()
```

I execute the binary testfile helloworldTest in Jenkins-> MyProject -> configuration -> Build -> Add build step: Execute Windows batch command

I get this output

```
> Hello World Test...
> Count World...

--- Results ---
Tests run:    2
Passes:       2
Failures:     0
```

If all tests pass, Jenkins Build Success (blue ball), if any test fails the Build fails (red ball).

Comment: Unit testing with C would usually earn you an upvote by me but your question is too broad and it's not clear for me what you're asking. Please cut it down to individual problems (1 question per question) instead of dumping a huge amount of text on us.

Comment: Hope I have improved my question now.

Comment: "my simple C code in Notepad++" - that's your first mistake. As a solo developer, you need an IDE long before you need Jenkins 9and learn how to use the debugger). Don't get me wrong, I use both Jenkins and version control on private projects, but a new code will get far more benefit from an IDE than from Jenkins. Try Eclipse CDT, Code::Blocks, MSVC, NetBeans ... whatever you want, but do use an IDE